# Hash to 16 characters

Tags: c#, hash

Id like to produce a fixed length of 16 characters by hashing an input string.
I'd prefer not to do something like taking a hash like SHA256 and then just taking the first few characters.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Cryptographic hashes should be considerably longer than 16 characters if they are to provide adequate collision resistance. The MD5 algorithm produces a hash of 32 hex digits (approx. 22 base64 characters), but has already been thoroughly broken. Storing a SHA256 hash in binary as a sequence of 32 bytes is perfectly acceptable, but your idea of handling this data as a string of 16 UTF-16 characters makes about as much sense as storing it in an array of four double-precision floating-point variables (i.e., none whatsoever).

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with storing/handling data... It is a requirement for a 3rd party api to have a unique fixed length string of 16. I need to be able to reproduce this unique reference by hashing the original data. I'm stunned by the requirement of this api with that fixed string length specification is just ridiculous. Hence, the strange question... I just want to handle this the best way possible, but if I have to I'll just take a few "chars" from SHA256 or even MD5 and be done with it. Which I don't want to do, which is why I'm asking this question...

Comment: If you need unique 16-character strings in order to interface with a third-party API, then just use sequential 16-digit hex numbers. These are *guaranteed* to be unique (until the digits overflow after 18 quintillion updates). I can't think of any situation where you would need *cryptographic* hashes to interface with a third-party API, but you did add the `cryptography` tag to this question, so perhaps you can explain?

Comment: You could use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: My bad I removed the `cryptography` tag, however `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` will work! I like :D

Comment: @squeamishossifrage can't be sequential it needs to be unique globally eg. kindof like a guid, and reproducible from the data hence the hashing part.

Comment: @Aldracor OK then, how about concatenating the process ID (8 hex digits) with an incrementing unsigned integer (8 hex digits). If your data records don't include unique IDs, then *add them*. Please don't use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` — this is a slow and computationally expensive function (deliberately so). The first 16 chars of a SHA256 hash would work just as well, and a lot faster. But if you need to calculate these hash values every time you want to access your data, then something is wrong with your code design.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I don't need to access the data with this. It's not what hashes are for.. I have unique Ids and they are `int`. Why am I even explaining this to you? How would using process Id be reproducible, and be unique **GLOBALLY**? And I know `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is intentionally slow and expensive (even with 1 iteration) for reasons I don't need and then there is the problem of the salt I would need to store, but so far it's the only real solution to the problem, besides performance issues. *FYI I'm probalby only going to process around 1 in 5 secs at most in the foreseeable future*

Comment: You mention "string" and "characters", but those are not precise enough to address your problem of encoding bytes. You **must** also specify a character set to answer your question. Common character sets include url-safe variants, base64, and UTF-8.

Comment: @JamesKPolk No I just need a string, I don't care what the characters look like nor what encoding they are based of.

Answer (score -2):

- SHA-256 produces 256 bits
- Unicode uses 16 bits per character

**Therefore: (256/16 = 16)**

256 bits from hash / 16 bits character set = 16 characters!

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.ASCII;
byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(uniqueString);

var crypto = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = crypto.ComputeHash(buffer);

return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hash); //16 characters
```

Comment: `Unicode uses 16 bits per character` You're confusing Unicode with UTF-16 and Character with code-units.

Comment: Unicode doesn’t use 16 bits per character and not all code points are characters anyway.

Comment: Well, `Encoding.Unicode` "Returns: An encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order".
But "not all code points are characters", ‍♂️yup you're right. 

Comment: C# calls it Unicode which is wrong, you don't need to make the same mistake. You can't interpret any random bytestream as UTF-16 because not all byte-sequences are valid code-units, not all code-unit sequences are valid code-points, and not all code-points are valid. And on top of that, not all Code-Points are printable, so if you want to print the string somehow, you won't be able to. If you don't, why not just store the bytes as-is?

Comment: I would've if I could, a third party API requires the fixed width string with a length of 16. So I can't just store the bytes unfortunately.